# Unnest Arrays with Jolt Transform

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I'm trying to convert a JSON object which contains an array and unnest the data into seperate JSON objects. Basically I need to create an object for each element of the array with all the external data duplicated. The example:

INPUT

```
{
  "id": 3435,
  "startTime": "2019-10-30T10:00:00Z",
  "sportType": "FOOTBALL",
  "participants": [
    {
      "id": 1234,
      "name": "Team A",
      "position": "HOME"
    },
    {
      "id": 5678,
      "name": "Team B",
      "position": "AWAY"
    }
  ]
}
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
{
  "id": 3435,
  "startTime": "2019-10-30T10:00:00Z",
  "sportType": "FOOTBALL",
  "participant_id": 1234,
  "participant_name": "Team A"
  "participant_position": "HOME"
},
{
  "id": 3435,
  "startTime": "2019-10-30T10:00:00Z",
  "sportType": "FOOTBALL",
  "participant_id": 5678,
  "participant_name": "Team B"
  "participant_position": "AWAY"
}
```

SPEC I tried:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "id": "newID",
      "startTime": "startTime",
      "sportType": "sportType",
      "participants": {
        "*": {
          "id": "participant.&1.participant_id",
          "name": "participant.&1.participant_name",
          "position": "participant.&1.participant_position"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I am very new with Jolt and tried a couple of SPECS which did not work. I am having trouble with the unnesting part. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This spec should work:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "participants": {
        "*": {
          "id": "[#2].participant_id",
          "name": "[#2].participant_name",
          "position": "[#2].participant_position",
          "@(2,id)": "[#2].id",
          "@(2,startTime)": "[#2].startTime",
          "@(2,sportType)": "[#2].sportType"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

For completeness, ForkRecord and FlattenJson do similar things to the above spec, might be easier to use those than trying to figure out JOLT specs.

Comment: Thank you for this it is exactly what I needed. Can you maybe explain what is happening in the SPEC so I can understand how it works. Also I am trying the modify this to get it to work with multiple nested arrays or another array in another object. Any pointers to how I could achieve that? Thank you.

Comment: The `*` iterates over each object in the object/array, but I believe it actually creates 2 levels, first the array index, then the object itself. So using `@(2,id)` goes up 2 levels and matches the `id` field, and `[#2]` uses the array index in the outgoing object array. For more nested arrays, you might need to go up to the top-level parent index sometimes (maybe `[#4]` or something) or just the current array index.